# C# Windows not opening on top

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a relatively large application with lots of dialog boxes and forms, etc.
I'm opening them with `Form.ShowDialog()`.

A lot of the time, the forms open behind existing windows, e.g. yesterday I was testing it on a machine with several other programs open: many Windows Explorer windows, a few Excel windows, etc. A lot of my forms, open/save file dialogs, etc were supposed to open but didn't. I was twiddling my thumbs until I pressed alt+tab and realised that they were, in fact, behind another window.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it in future? Thanks.

Comment: Does the parent window have focus when the boxes are displayed?

Comment: @minitech Yes. It's usually a button click, menu click, etc which causes the form to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) override which takes an owner window as a parameter.

By passing in your main window as the dialog's owner, you guarantee that the dialog always pops in front of it, and stays in front of it.

And it won't annoy the user if they were using some other application.

Comment: This is the only correct way to do it, and the only correct answer in this thread.

Comment: His problem description is a little lacking...does he really want all of his forms to be modal?  I doubt it..but I could be wrong.

Comment: They are child forms; one of the core functions of the OS's window manager is to manage child forms so they don't popup behind the parent. He needs to set the parent window correctly, and this is how it is done by default. If he doesn't want modality, then there are other ways to create child windows without it, but retain the parent-child relationship.

Comment: @alexD: All `ShowDialog` overrides create modal dialogs, and he said in the question he's using `ShowDialog`, so I think yes they are supposed to be modal.

Comment: @codekaizen: owner is not the same as parent.  For example, a child window is restricted to the boundaries of its parent, an owned dialog is not.

Comment: @alexD ShowDialog() is Modal vs Show() which is not. In any case, about 95% of my dialogs are modal. I will give the override a try. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - sorry, yes, Owner is correct. I had forgotten the distinction.